How to maximize yield of caffeine extracted from tea with water?
I am doing a report on extraction of caffeine for my O-chem finals and I am confused whether to use freshly plucked tea leaves or dried tea leaves for the extraction. I want to yield the maximum amount of caffeine from the tea leaves. Also, what is the expected yield of caffeine when extracting by boiling fresh tea leaves?

Did you make any searches? Not fresh leaves will have plenty of water, dried leaves will have less, so we cannot compare by mass basis...

Drying might interfere with degradation of caffeine. It is otherwise nonvolatile, so if the material is digested properly and allowed to soak long enough the yield should be comparable.

There is a chemical apparatus that allows continuous extraction from solids which will maximise the amount of partly soluble things from solids: the Soxhlet apparatus. This is probably a good way to maximise extraction.

Use dried leaves, and grind them with a pestle and mortar. Once crushed, add ethanol or another solvent into the mortar and mix it into a paste. Transfer this paste into a vessel with further solvent. Heat the mixture, preferably using a heat gun or heat plate instead of boiling it. Allow the solution to settle and decant the dissolved component.
